# Как вывести картинку в yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь вывести картинку из базы во вьюшке, путь до папки с картинкой такой backend/web/images. Вот такой код во вьюшке:

```
<?= Html::img(@backend.'/web/' .$model->image) ?>
```

Вроде в браузере выводится путь

```
<img src="backend/web/images/13363.jpg" alt="">
```

но ссылка почему-то битая. Подскажите пожалуйста, что тут не так?

Comment: Может быть потому что у вас корень сайта это папка web. А судя по ссылке вы ищете картинку в `backend/web/backend/web/images/13363.jpg`
Путь должен быть `/images/13363.jpg`
Предположу что у вас разделение на backend и frontend взято из advanced template. А как они у вас разделяются через саб домен или URL?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то они разделяются так: backend.site.loc и site.loc

Comment: Ну тогда если картинка тянется из `site.loc`, то у вас ссылка должна быть`http://backend.site.loc/images/13363.jpg` если с `backend.site.loc`, то можно просто `/images/13363.jpg`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В конфиге

```
'components' => [
    'urlManagerBackend' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'baseUrl' => '//backend.site.loc',
        //..
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'baseUrl' => '//site.loc',
        //..
    ],
],
```

И использование

```
//Картинка находится в **backend/web**
<?= Html::img(Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl($model->image)) ?>

//Картинка находится в **frontend/web**
<?= Html::img(Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl($model->image)) ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это помогло!